# How to use timeout to stop blocking function subscribe.simple

Tags: python-3.x, synchronization, mqtt, paho

I want to use timeout to stop the blocking function of mqtt, I use a the timeout_decorator module, it can stop command function but cannot stop blocking function, `subscribe.simple`.

The following code runs successfully

```
import time
import timeout_decorator

@timeout_decorator.timeout(5, timeout_exception=StopIteration)
def mytest():
    print("Start")
    for i in range(1,10):
        time.sleep(1)
        print("{} seconds have passed".format(i))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mytest()
```

the result as follow:

```
Start
1 seconds have passed
2 seconds have passed
3 seconds have passed
4 seconds have passed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "timeutTest.py", line 12, in <module>
    mytest()
  File "/home/gyf/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/timeout_decorator/timeout_decorator.py", line 81, in new_function
    return function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "timeutTest.py", line 8, in mytest
    time.sleep(1)
  File "/home/gyf/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/timeout_decorator/timeout_decorator.py", line 72, in handler
    _raise_exception(timeout_exception, exception_message)
  File "/home/gyf/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/timeout_decorator/timeout_decorator.py", line 45, in _raise_exception
    raise exception()
timeout_decorator.timeout_decorator.TimeoutError: 'Timed Out'
```

but I failed with the subscribe.simple API

```
import timeout_decorator

@timeout_decorator.timeout(5)
def sub():
    # print(type(msg))
    print("----before simple")
    # threading.Timer(5,operateFail,args=)
    msg = subscribe.simple("paho/test/simple", hostname=MQTT_IP,port=MQTT_PORT,)
    print("----after simple")
    return msg


publish.single("paho/test/single", "cloud to device", qos=2, hostname=MQTT_IP,port=MQTT_PORT)
try:
    print("pub")
    msg = sub()
    print(msg)
except StopIteration as identifier:
    print("error")
```

The result infinitely wait

```
pub
----before simple
```

I want the function which include subscribe.simple API can stop after 5 seconds.

Comment: Why does it have to `subscribe.simple()`? Why not use normal client subscription handling and a separate thread to keep track of pending requests?

Comment: Because I need to wait the device's response to displays whether the operation was successful on the page. If I use multithreading, the main thread which plan to return 200 or 404 response according to the response of the child thread that use normal client will directly to the end

Comment: did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Asyncio won't be able to handle blocking function in the same thread. therefore using `asyncio.wait_for` failed. However, inspired by [this blog post](https://carlosmaniero.github.io/asyncio-handle-blocking-functions.html) I used `loop.run_in_executor` to keep control on the blocking thread.

```
from paho.mqtt import subscribe
import asyncio

MQTT_IP = "localhost"
MQTT_PORT = 1883
msg = None


def possibly_blocking_function():
    global msg
    print("listenning for message")
    msg = subscribe.simple(
        "paho/test/simple",
        hostname=MQTT_IP,
        port=MQTT_PORT,
    )
    print("message received!")


async def main():
    print("----before simple")
    try:
        await asyncio.wait_for(
            loop.run_in_executor(None, possibly_blocking_function), timeout=5
        )
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        pass
    print("----after simple")

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Output :

```
----before simple
listenning for message
----after simple
```

Please note this is not perfect, the program won't end since there are running tasks. You can exit it using various solution but this is out of scope since I am still looking for a clean way to close that stuck thread.